# Relationships Between 3 Tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Relationships between Tables

[image: Relationships between Tables]

This is a True or Not???
and what is the Key of Table 3 ?

Comment: please explain your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

The point is you don't need any relation between Table1 and Table3!

Relations between tables are being used to point to a specific record of data using a primary key (usually an ID), which in this chart you can find that specific record of Table1 using the relation between Table2 and Table3.

I hope this answer helps :)

Comment: Tank's For Your Help